# Gauss Divergence Theorem in the Plane..

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $F:\mathbb R^2\longrightarrow \mathbb R^2$ be a $C^1$ vector field, $F(x, y)=(P(x, y), Q(x, y))$. Consider the smooth curve $\gamma:[0, 2\pi]\longrightarrow \mathbb R^2$ given by $\gamma(t)=(\sin(t), \cos(t))$ and let $B=\{(x, y)\in\mathbb R^2: x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$. How can I show that $$-\int_{\gamma} F\cdot \nu \ ds=\int\int_B\textrm{div}(F)\ dA,$$ where $\nu$ is the unit normal vector to $\gamma(t)$.

**My Atempt:** Firstly notice $\nu(\gamma(t))=(\sin(t), \cos(t))$ and $\|\gamma^{'}(t)\|=1$. Hence,
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle -\int_{\gamma}F\cdot \nu\ ds&=-\int_{0}^{2\pi} \langle F(\gamma(t)), \nu(\gamma(t))\rangle\|\gamma^{'}(t)\|\ dt\\
&=-\int_{0}^{2\pi} P(\gamma(t))\sin(t)+Q(\gamma(t))\cos(t)\ dt\\
&=-\int_{\gamma} P\ dx+Q\ dy\\
&=-\int\int_{B} \left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right)\ dA\\
&=\int\int_B\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}\right)\ dA,
\end{align*}
but I don't know how to finish the proof.. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You've got a sign error, because $$- \left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} \right) \neq \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Your error occurs when you change from $dt$ to $dx$ and $dy$. You say $dx = \sin t~dt$, but $dx = d(\sin t) = \cos t~dt$, and similarly, $dy = -\sin t~dt$. That leaves you with
$$- \int_\gamma Q~dx - P~dy = \int_\gamma P~dy - Q~dx$$
by Green's theorem, this is
$$ \iint_B \left( \frac{\partial P}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial Q}{\partial y}\right)~dA$$
as expected.